# Get index of a view inside a NSCollectionView?

Tags: cocoa, indexing, nstableview, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I've developed an app for Mac OS X Lion using its new view-based NSTableView, but as I want to port the whole app to Snow Leopard I'm trying to figure out the best way to emulate such a tableview. So far I've created a NSCollectionView and everything is fine, except for the fact that I can't get the index of the view from which a button click event is triggered.
In Lion I have the following function:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
```

so I can get the index of the view inside the tableview using a method (I can't remember its name) like

```
- (NSInteger)rowForView:(NSView *)aView
```

with aView being the sender's superview, but I couldn't find something similar for the collection view ... The only "useful" method seems to be

```
- (NSCollectionViewItem *)itemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

(or something like this), but this can't help me as it returns a NSCollectionViewItem and I can't even access it knowing only the corresponding view!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within buttonClick, try this code:

```
id collectionViewItem = [sender superview];
NSInteger index = [[collectionView subviews]  indexOfObject:collectionViewItem];
return index;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I can't believe it, it seems to work! I'm not sure this is the best was to achieve this (Apple should have implemented a better method) but anyway this solves my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: A word of warning: this does not work anymore once the view items are reordered (e.g. if you support rearranging by drag & drop).

Answer (score 2):

Geesh! Both of those approaches have issues.  I can see how the first on may work, but note that the "collectionViewItem" is actually the view, NOT the collectionViewItem, which is a view controller.

The second way will not work, unless you subclass the button and put in a back link to the collectionViewItem.  Otherwise, your view does not know what collectionViewItem controls it. You should use a selector binding to the collectionViewItem's representedObject instead, to get the action to the correct object in your array.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
id obj = [collectonViewItem representedObject];
NSInteger index = [[collectionView contents] indexOfObject:obj];
```

Comment: Like I said, I can't access the collectonViewItem only knowing the view representing it ...

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested here: [How to handle a button click from NSCollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326420/how-to-handle-a-button-click-from-nscollectionview/18477969#18477969)

I would do it like this (because the button you want to press should be coupled with the corresponding model, therefore the represented object):

1. Add a method to the model of your collectionViewItem (e.g. buttonClicked)
2. Bind the Button Target to Collection View Item
3. While binding set model key path to: representedObject
4. While binding set selectorname to: methodname you chose earlier (e.g. buttonClicked)
5. Add protocol to your model, if you must tell delegate or establish observer-pattern

Answer (score 0):

1. use NSArrayController for binding to NSCollectionView,
2. use collectonViewItem.representedObject to get a Custom Model defined by yourself.
3. save and get index in your custom model.

That's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve this:

- For the collection view item, create a dedicated `NSView` subclass and use this as the main container class in the collection view item XIB. By this I mean the `view` property of your `NSCollectionViewItem` instance should point to this dedicated class.
- Then, in you button action, you need to find super views of the button:

  - The dedicated container class, mentioned above.
  - The collection view.
  - (Your view hierarchy will roughly be something like `collection view > item view > button`, so these two views should always exist, unless the container is not visible.)
- When you got all this information, you can iterate over the collection views's `visibleItems`. The item you're looking for is the one with `item.view == yourContainerView`.

---

First, let's create a helper method on `NSView`:

```swift
extension NSView {
    
    /// The receiver or one of its super views matching the given class.
    func enclosingView<T>(type: T.Type) -> T? {
        var cursor: NSView? = self
        
        while let current = cursor {
            if let match = cursor as? T {
                return match
            }
            
            cursor = current.superview
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
}
```

Using this, the search for the item works like this:

```swift
let button: NSButton = yourButtonInstance
guard
    let container = button.enclosingView(type: YourContainer.self), 
    let collectionView = button.enclosingView(type: NSCollectionView.self),
    let item = collectionView.visibleItems().first(where: { $0.view == container })
else {
    return
}

/// `item` now is the NSCollectionViewItem instance associated with your button.
```